# How to get access token from Angular single page application for multiple web API applications created in B2C tenant

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to implement angular single page application with B2C authentication.
Multiple micro services created for different purpose. I have created 
different Applications for all the micro services under B2C tenant.
taken help from below URL
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/

I am unable to use the token acquired for one Web API application is to other WEB API application.

Is there a way to use single access token for multiple micro services using B2C authentication.

trying to find solution in google since last one moth but no luck.

Some body can help me on this issue. What is the best approach to implement micro services concept using Azure AD B2C authentication. any sample would be a great help

Comment: Hi @Murthy. Can I suggest an alternate approach that simplifies the authentication model but maintains the microservice pattern? That is, all microservices APIs are registered in Azure AD B2C as a *single* application, where access by clients to them is managed using scopes. This means a single token, containing scopes for access to one or more microservice APIs, can be issued to a client application. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update Chris.
->  all microservices APIs are registered in Azure AD B2C as a single application (Meaning single application with multiple return URL's?).
-> where access by the client to them is managed using scopes.(How can we manage different scopes for different return URL's in single application).
Please provide .Net MVC/Angular sample for this approach would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi @Murthy. APIs, by definition, don't require any redirect URLs; it's the client applications that require these so that tokens can be returned to them. So, all microservice APIs can be registered as a single application with a single redirect URL, e.g. `http://localhost`. See [the **Tutorial: Grant access to an ASP.NET Core web API from a single-page application using Azure Active Directory B2C** article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-tutorials-spa-webapi) for how to configure the API scopes and grant access for them.

Comment: Thanks for the update @ChrisPadgett, As you mentioned in the update, I have created single application for all the different micro service APIs and I have used the single API application client id in all the micro services web.config file but the token acquired for API application is not working for other API. getting authorization error. but First API is working fine with authorization.

Comment: Does the `scp` (scope) claim in the access token contain the required value for the second API?

Comment: there is no separate scope defined for second micro service API as I am using single API application for different micro service APIs. I am using Owin middle ware library for acquiring tokens. Getting authorization error When I use the token for other micro service.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support @ChrisPadgett. I have found the root cause for authorization error for second API call. Reason is that partial startup class is missed in second micro service code.